# MASM32 (Lib: Irvine32) Weird variable behavior

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32, masm32

the problem is, that the if-statement is true multiple times, so the variable "iDATA"
is 100 again, but at the same time, when I print the var after the if-statement, then it doesnt say that it's 100 and just goes up from 0-x, like you would expect it.

```
.data
iDATA DWORD 0

.code

main PROC
    loop0:
        mov eax, iDATA
        .if eax == 100
            call WriteInt
        .endif
        add iDATA, 1
    jmp loop0
main ENDP

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
END main
```

output: +100+100+100+100+100+100+100+100...

pls explain me where my error is

Comment: `WriteInt` expects the argument in `eax`, not `edx`.

Comment: @Michael changed it, but the output is the same

Comment: `.if`/`.endif` are *assembler directives*; they either include the indicated code in the resulting object code, or omit it, no run-time comparison is being performed here.  You'd need some sort of `cmp` opcode to do that.

Comment: @jasonharper tried it with cmp and also gives the same output

Comment: @jasonharper `.if` in MASM syntax is a runtime check. Conditional assembly is done with `if` (without the leading period).

Comment: There's no code inside your loop there will ever exit the loop. And since you've got an infinite loop, the value at `iData` will eventually wrap around to 0 again, and then reach 100 again soon after that, and so on.

Comment: Like I said, if you never exit the loop then you'll get an infinite sequence of `0 .. 100 .. 2^32-1, 0 .. 100 .. 2^32-1, 0 ..`. If that's not what you want then you should exit the loop once the condition you're waiting for has been fulfilled. The part about conditional assembly was in reply to another commenter and isn't really relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Michael oh, now i understand the error
can you give me a good solution for fixing this, without exiting the loop?
(want a main-loop, that always loops)

Comment: Having a tight loop like that running indefinitely doesn't sound like a great idea, since it might bog down the CPU core it's running on. In any case, if you want the value 100 to be printed only once, then you may need to use another variable/register to keep track of whether you've printed the value 100 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it re-looped, because of overflow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).